# How can I get the region and culture info for Bahamas?

Tags: c#, .net, globalization

```
Country                                         A 2     A 3     Number
----------------------------------------------------------------------
BAHAMAS                                         BS      BHS     044
```

The country already exists, but I can't get the region and culture info from the .Net API.

```
RegionInfo r = new RegionInfo("BS"); or RegionInfo r = new RegionInfo("BSH");
RegionInfo r = new RegionInfo(44)
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(44)
```

Question: How do I get region and culture information for the country?

ISO 3166: http://userpage.chemie.fu-berlin.de/diverse/doc/ISO_3166.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is interesting, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bahamas), the official language is English with a [Bahmanian Dialect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahamian_Dialect).

When trying these, we get the following errors

```
BHS - the culture is not supported
```

(by the was your code has BSH, typo probably)

With "BS", you get:

```
**The region name BS should not correspond to neutral culture; a 
specific culture name is required.**
```

So I did some research, for a specific culture, turns out [there is a language subtag](http://people.w3.org/rishida/utils/subtags/index.php?find=eng&submit=Find) for **Bahamas Creole English** which is "bah"

However - this also yields:

```
Culture name 'bah-BS' is not supported.
```

Turns out, .NET doesn't support all known culture regions - it uses the list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). (used 3.5 link - the list disappears in 4.0 version - maybe hasn't been updated)

Unfortunately you will need to [build a custom culture/region for The Bahamas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).